# Validating Record<string, string[]> using class-validator

Tags: validation, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to validate Record<string, string[]> but it's not working.

Here is what my custom decorator looks like

```
import {
  isObject,
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidationOptions,
} from 'class-validator';

export const IsRecord = (
  key_validators: ((value: string) => boolean)[],
  value_validators: ((value: string[]) => boolean)[],
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) => {
  return function (object: unknown, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsRecord',
      target: (object as any).constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: unknown, args: ValidationArguments) {
          if (!isObject(value)) return false;
          const keys = Object.keys(value);

          return keys.some(key => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
            const is_key_invalid = key_validators.some(
              validator => !validator(key),
            );
            if (is_key_invalid) return false;

            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
            // @ts-ignore
            return value_validators.some(validator => !validator(value[key]));
          });
        },
      },
    });
  };
};
```

I'm gonna be using this AutoRegisterDto in my controller to specify the body type.

```
import {
  BaseRole,
  ModuleName,
  Topic,
} from 'my-package';
import { IsBoolean, IsEnum, IsObject, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';
import { IsRecord } from './decorators/is-record.decorator';

export class AutoRegisterDto {
  @IsEnum(ModuleName)
  name: ModuleName;

  @IsBoolean()
  isEnabled: boolean;

  @IsObject()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsRecord([], [])
  actions: Record<Topic, BaseRole[]>;
}
```

BaseRole Enum

```
export declare enum BaseRole {
    UNREGISTERED_GUEST = "unregistered_user",
    UNVERIFIED_GUEST = "unverified_guest",
    VERIFIED_GUEST = "verified_guest",
    STUDENT = "student",
    EMPLOYEE = "employee",
    ADMIN = "admin"
}
```

and Topic

```
export declare type Topic = string;
```

I tried to solve it following answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576734/validate-each-mapstring-number-value-using-class-validator) but it didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue in this way, I carefully read the documentation of class-validator.

```
export const IsRecord = (validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) => {
  return function (object: unknown, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsRecord',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: {
        message: 'Wrong object format',
        ...validationOptions,
      },
      validator: {
        validate(value: unknown, args: ValidationArguments) {
          if (!isObject(value)) return false;
          if (Object.keys(value).length === 0) return true;
          const keys = Object.keys(value);

          return keys.every(key => {
            if (typeof key != 'string') return false;

            return Array.isArray(value[key]) && value[key].every(val => Object.values(BaseRole).includes(val));
          });
        },
      },
    });
  };
};
```

This validates an empty object or an object with keys of type string and value array of enum BaseRole.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';

export const IsRecord = (validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) => {
  return function (object: unknown, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsRecord',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: {
        message: 'Wrong object format',
        ...validationOptions,
      },
      validator: {
        validate(value: unknown, args: ValidationArguments) {
          if (!isObject(value)) return false;
          if (Object.keys(value).length === 0) return true;

          const keys = Object.keys(value);

          return keys.every(key => {
            if (typeof key !== 'string') return false;
            if (!Array.isArray(value[key])) return false;
            if (!value[key].every(val => typeof val === 'string')) return false;

            return true;
          });
        },
      },
    });
  };
};
```

Now add `@IsRecord` validator to the property

It iterate over the keys and perform the following checks:

- `if (typeof key !== 'string') return false;`
- ensures that all keys are strings. `if (!Array.isArray(value[key])) return false;`
- checks that the corresponding value is an array. `if (!value[key].every(val => typeof val === 'string')) return false;`
- validates that all elements in the array are strings.